# Always execute method after constructor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

I have a situation where I always need to run a certain bit of code that depends on the object itself

```
public abstract class A{
    public A(X x){
        //init A stuff
        x.getAList("stuff").add(this);
        x.getAList("otherstuff").add(this);
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    public B(X x){
        super(x);
        //init B stuff
    }
}

public class C extends A{
    public C(X x){
        super(x);
        //init C stuff
        x.getAList("otherstuff").remove(this);
        x.getAList("morestuff").add(this);
    }
}

public class SomeClass{
    private X someX;

    public A somefunc(boolean b){
        if(b){
            return new B(someX);
        }else{
            return new C(someX);
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem is the following. In this example I use `this` in the constructor. If another thread tries to access the object through someX.getAList, it could cause that thread to get access to the object before the constructor has ended.

You could make it so that the object gets added to the AList by somefunc

```
public class SomeClass{
    private X someX;

    public A somefunc(boolean b){
        A a;
        if(b){
            a = new B(someX);
            someX.getAList("stuff").add(a);
            someX.getAList("otherstuff").add(a);
        }else{
            a = new C(someX);
            someX.getAList("stuff").add(a);
            someX.getAList("morestuff").add(a);
        }
        return a;
    } 
}
```

The problem is that B's and C's could also be instantiated elsewhere and that everytime a B or C is created they would need to be added in that specified way. I don't want adding the object to the AList to be the responsibility of the user, but of the class. I also don't want the user to have to call an init function that does this for them. On the other hand, I don't want any concurrency issues.

Is there a way or a pattern that makes it possible to implement this?

Golang has something like defer that lets you run a piece of code after the function/method/constructor is done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a Factory-Method for the super and subclass instead and make the constructors private, forcing everyone who wants an instance to use the factory method. A factory method is a method that returns a completely constructed instance. Once the instance is completely constructed (after the constructor was called in the factory method) add the instance to the list, that way no thread can get hold of a incomplete/non-finalized instance.

The point of the Factory-Method is to strictly isolate all the initialisation code from any non-initialisation code, to avoid access to and exposure of uninitialised fields. Also it can serve as a selector for users, automatically returning a suitable (sub-)type, without having to be specified.([Interesting design-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Patterns_by_Type))

```
abstract class A{
    protected A(){
        //constructor code goes here
    }
    public void afterFinalisation(final X x) {
        x.getAList("stuff").add(this);
        x.getAList("otherstuff").add(this);
    }
}

class B extends A{
    protected B(){
        super();
        //constructor code goes here
    }
    public static B create(final X x) {
        final B returnValue = new B();
        returnValue.afterFinalisation(x);
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class C extends A{
    protected C(){
        super();
        //constructor code goes here
    }
    @Override
    public void afterFinalisation(final X x) {
        super.afterFinalisation(x);
        x.getAList("otherstuff").remove(this);
        x.getAList("morestuff").add(this);
    }
    public static C create(final X x) {
        final C returnValue = new C();
        returnValue.afterFinalisation(x);
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class SomeClass{
    private final X someX = new X();

    public A somefunc(final boolean b){
        if(b){
            return B.create(this.someX);
        }else{
            return C.create(this.someX);
        }
    }
}
```

The credit for the constructor code goes to [coolcats iteration of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37381639/5191731), I was trying to avoid putting code into the protected constructors and worked with a init() method instead, which required a big unelegant-workaround for final fields.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Though your final version is a bit over the top, you did give me an idea how I want to structure my code, which you can see in my own submitted answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is the point of making object reference inside `create` methods `final`?

Comment: This makes sure that the instance put into the list and the one that is returned is the same. It cannot be reassigned at any point.

Comment: Problem with factories is that encapsulation can still be broken.

Answer (score 1):

By taking a few design decisions from [HopfullyHelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5191731/hopefullyhelpful) I end up with liking the following design best:

```
public abstract class A{

    protected A(X x){
        //constructor with all inits
    }
    protected A publish(X x) {
        x.getAList("stuff").add(this);
        x.getAList("otherstuff").add(this);
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    protected B(X x){
        super(x);
        //constructor with all inits
    }
    protected B publish(X x) {
        super.publish(x);
        return this;
    }
    public static B create(X x) {
        return new B(x).publish(x);
    }
}

class C extends A{
    protected C(X x){
        super(x);
        //constructor with all inits
    }
    protected void publish(X x) {
        super.publish(x);
        x.getAList("otherstuff").remove(this);
        x.getAList("morestuff").add(this);
        return this;
    }
    public static C create(X x) {
        return new C(x).publish(x);
    }
}

class SomeClass{
    private X someX;

    public A somefunc(boolean b){
        if(b){
            return B.create(this.someX);
        }else{
            return C.create(this.someX);
        }
    }
}
```